# "Undefined is not a function" error when calling a Backbone collection's fetch function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am getting an error when calling the `fetch` function.

```
Undefined is not a function Error in Backbone js
```

```js
var models = Backbone.Model.extend({
  userId: function() {
    return this.get('userId');
  },
  id: function() {
    return this.get('id');
  },
  body: function() {
    return this.get('body');
  }
});
//Collections
var todolistStore = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: function() {
    return 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  },
  model: models,
  parse: function(response) {
    return response;
  }
});
todolistStore.fetch();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to instantiate first: `var myStore = new todolistStore(); myStore.fetch();`

Comment: @ChrisG Still not working

Comment: You're using old versions of underscore and backbone. When I use current versions instead, the errors disappear.

Comment: You don't need to provide an `id` function as [Backbone already provides an `id` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id) that's linked to the `id` attribute.

Comment: Also, the `parse` function is useless if the data only passes through.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks for the help. Please tell me how can i load my collection only once for whole application and save that data?

Comment: That's way too vague to answer in a comment, look for tutorials, I've got a lot of topics covered in other [answers listed on my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218980/emile-bergeron?tab=profile). If you get blocked on a specific thing, just ask a new question!

Comment: @EmileBergeron okey thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. I'm building off of @ChrisG 's answer.

1. You need to instantiate a collection. Here's what my code:

   ```
   var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
       userId: function() {
           return this.get('userId');
       },
       id: function() {
           return this.get('id');
       },
       body: function() {
           return this.get('body');
       }
   });

   //Collections
   var TodoListStore = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       url: function() {
           return 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
       },
       model: Model,
       parse: function(response) {
           return response;
       }
   });

   var todolistStore = new TodoListStore();
   todolistStore.fetch();
   ```
2. I updated the version of Underscore and Backbone

   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js 
   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js